# Capacitance matrix of superconducting qubit

Tags: simulation, qiskit, superconducting-quantum-computing

I want to start to do some simulation and design of superconducting qubits. I want to start using qiskit metal, but in order to calculate the capacitance matrix I need to interface it with Ansys. Since I don't have Ansys I want to ask you if are there some free tools that I can use with the gds file of qiskit metal?

P.S I prefer something that can be instructive in order to link what I studied in theory with the practice

Comment: You can use [Amazon Palace](https://awslabs.github.io/palace/stable/) as an alternative to Ansys.

Comment: In this case should I do all the design on amazon palace, I don't need qiskit metal, right? Or are there some files that I can pass from qiskit metal to amazon palace?